# Extracting error code from json response in IOS

Tags: ios, json, nsinteger

```
{ 
ErrorCodes = ( 
   12 
); 
Success=0; 
}
```

I have json response like above and i am want to fetch 12 from error code so that i can display appropriate error message. I am doing like this

```
NSInteger err = [[dict objectForKey:@"ErrorCodes"] integerValue];
```

but this is giving exception error like

```
[__NSArrayM integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

what am i doing wrong? and how can i convert error code 12 into NSInteger...

Comment: Again again and again. Parsing data from JSON and unrecognized selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ErrorCodes` here is an array, and that is the reason you got the error. You should try something like this instead:

```
[[[dict objectForKey:@"ErrorCodes"] objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
```